# No value given for one or more required parameters. in Vb6.0

Tags: ms-access, parameters, vb6, ado, jet

```vb
Private Sub cmb_dept_name_LostFocus()
    Call CloseAllConnections

    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\Data.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"

    Dim q1 As String
    q1 = "Select * from master where dept=" &   cmb_dept_name.Text
    
    rs1.Open q1, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    Do While rs1.EOF
        cmb_deadstock_no.AddItem rs1.Fields("Dead_Stock_No")
        rs1.MoveNext
    Loop
        
    Call CloseAllConnections
End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't said which line is causing the error?

Comment: too much missing code for me, but I like to loop over the items in a recordset.  So try Do Until rs1.eof

Comment: As @mazoula alluded to, your loop control statement should be `Do Until rs1.EOF`; as it's written now, the loop will never execute unless the query returns no records, in which case it will fail with "No current record".

Comment: Where specifically does the error occur?

Answer (score 2):

Your value seems to be a *name*, thus text, so try with quotes:

```vb
q1 = "Select * from master where dept = '" & cmb_dept_name.Text & "'"
```